# Is this possible with Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets

I have two threads communicating via DatagramSockets. I would now like a third thread to be able to listen to the communication.  After reading [Broadcasting to Multiple Recipients](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) it seems that two MulticastSockets on the third thread is what I'm looking for.

However, I get a "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind" error when trying to bind the MulticastSockets to the same ports that the DatagramSockets are using in the first two threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of some of the answers and comments here I have solved it by doing the following.

I changed the 2 original threads to use Multicast sockets to communicate, and the third thread now has 2 Mulitcast sockets bound to these ports so it can listen to the communication.  Probably not the most beautiful solution, but it will suffice for my needs

Answer (score 0):

Well, your getting the exception because you cannot bind multiple sockets to the same port. If you want to support both point to point and multicast then you will need to designate different ports for each. Otherwise if you are always doing multicast broadcast then you can just drop the regular datagram sockets altogether.

Comment: Yes you can provided (in Java) they are all MulticastSockets.

Comment: Your answer is 100% incorrect, it's as simple as that. So is your comment, which applies to TCP, not UDP.

Comment: I should have added 'or they have all had `setReuseAddress(true)` called on them, which is the default for `MulticastSocket`.'

Answer (score 0):

You have two threads in the same program communicating via socket? How about creating a [queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) for them so it is just in process communication?

Comment: I agree about the queue, but re your 2nd paragraph, yes you can, provided (in Java) they are all MulticastSockets.

Comment: I read his question as attempting to use the port that the Datagram is already on to receive multicast packets.

Comment: If all the sockets in question have had `setReuseAddress(true)` called on them, which is the default for `MulticastSocket`, they can share the same port.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I deleted that part.